# Group by and sum up - AWK SCRIPT

Tags: awk, group-by, gawk

I have millions of data looking like:

```
TOTALOCTETSUNIT SERVEDACCOUNT   SERVICECLASSID  ACCUMULATEDUNITS    ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED    ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE  ACCOUNTVALUEAFTER
850             66498336         70             10240                10240                   0.083333           0.083333
259             64625247         41             10240                10240                   65.500000          65.50000
219792          76608974         35             225280               225280                  653.049798         653.049798
15261           76900654         35             20480                20480                   35.516666          35.516666
```

I have to group by SERVEDACCOUNT then SERVICECLASSID and then based on the result of this group by i have to sum up TOTALOCTETSUNIT, ACCUMULATEDUNITS, ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED, and ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE
It will not be a problem if the sum up where based on only one field but we have to group by using 2 fields

here is the awk script I'm using save as test.awk

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" } NR > 2500 {exit}            
1 < NR && NR <= 2500 { 
#sub(/ .*/,"",$4)      
key=$3
TOTOCTET[key]+=$1
ACCUNITS[key]+=$4
ACCUNITTED[key]+=$5
ACCVALBEF[key]+=$6} END {
printf "%-13s %18s %18s %18s %18s\n", 
    "SERVEDACCOUNT","TOTALOCTETSUNIT","ACCUMULATEDUNITS","ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED","ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE" 
for (i in TOTOCTET) { 
    printf "%-4s %16.6f %16.6f %16.6f %16.6f\n", 
        i,TOTOCTET[i],ACCUNITS[i],ACCUNITTED[i],ACCVALBEF[i] }
}
```

to run the script I'm using 
$ awk -f test file.txt

The output i got is a set of 0 like:

```
enterSERVEDACCOUNT    TOTALOCTETSUNIT   ACCUMULATEDUNITS ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE 
0.000000               0.000000         0.000000         0.000000         0.000000
0.000000               0.000000         0.000000         0.000000         0.000000
0.000000              279.000000         0.000000         0.000000         0.000000
```

Here is the output i'm looking for:

```
SERVEDACCOUNT   SERVICECLASSID  TOTALOCTETSUNIT ACCUMULATEDUNITS    ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED    ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE
64625247         41               259           10240                  10240                  65,5
66498336         70               850           10240                  10240                 0,083333
76608974         35               219792        225280                225280                  653,049798
76900654         35               15261          20480                 20480                   35,516666
```

Answer (score 0):

At present the key is being set to `$3` but if the key has to be determined by `SERVEDACCOUNT` and `SERVICECLASSID`, then the key should be based on both `$2` and `$3`, e.g.:

```
BEGIN { FS = "\t" } 
1 < NR && NR <= 2500 {
    key=$2 "-" $3
    TOTOCTET[key]+=$1
    ACCUNITS[key]+=$4
    ACCUNITTED[key]+=$5
    ACCVALBEF[key]+=$6} END {
    printf "%-13s %18s %18s %18s %18s %18s\n", 
    "SERVEDACCOUNT","SERVICECLASSID","TOTALOCTETSUNIT",
    "ACCUMULATEDUNITS","ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED","ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE" 
    for (i in TOTOCTET) {
        split(i,ii,/-/)
        printf "%-16s %-16s %16.0f %16.0f %16.0f %16.0f\n", 
        ii[1],ii[2],TOTOCTET[i],ACCUNITS[i],ACCUNITTED[i],ACCVALBEF[i] 
        }
    }
```

... which outputs:

```
SERVEDACCOUNT     SERVICECLASSID    TOTALOCTETSUNIT   ACCUMULATEDUNITS ACCOUNTUNITSDEDUCTED ACCOUNTVALUEBEFORE
76900654         35                          15261            20480            20480               36
66498336         70                            850            10240            10240                0
64625247         41                            259            10240            10240               66
76608974         35                         219792           225280           225280              653
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon for you answer! I executed the code given but i still have the same output i got previously (set of 0 )! 
Any idea about what's the problem ?

Comment: I suggest checking the field separator (`FS`) that you are using. You had initially used the pipe (`|`) but I changed it to tab, guessing that was the actual field separator and I used a tab-separated test file. If you have spaces between the fields or whitespace, you will need to set `FS` appropriately. Since you don't have any spaces in labels or field contents, just using whitespace would be appropriate. That is the default, so you won't have to set `FS` at all.